# Delete parameters in opening a link on browser

Tags: angular, browser, frontend

We have SMS service for retrieve our application password. However, in some phone browser and surprisingly in some time, when we click on retrieve  password link in SMS, browser delete parameters in change password link and because of that we cannot change password. Anybody can help us?
for example we sent this link in sms:

```
example.com/resetpass?token=123456
```

but when we click on this link and browser opened, we saw this link in address bar

```
example.com/resetpass
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the address bar and what the browser sends are two different things. Many modern browsers hide the parameters in the address until you actively click into the bar or even then you can only see it, if you copy the full address from the bar into notepad.

Another possibility would be that the web server, that receives the request, simply rewrites the url in its answer, but still does the intended work.

So before blaming the browser really check what's going on the wire (e.g. open DevTools, use Fiddler or Wireshark, etc.) and / or on the server side.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your first guess is not correct, because i click on address bar and i did not see any parameters. For your second guess, i have an important question: why in some phones we can see all parameters and we can change password. more interestingly, in some times one browser shows parameters and in some time no.